# Why is docker-compose failing with ERROR internal load metadata suddenly?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been running docker-compose build for days, many times per day, and haven't changed my DOCKERFILEs or docker-compose.yml. Suddenly an hour ago I started getting this:

```
Building frontdesk-api
failed to get console mode for stdout: The handle is invalid.
[+] Building 10.0s (3/4)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
[+] Building 10.1s (4/4) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.  10.0sailed to do request: Head https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/dotnet/sdk/manifests/5.0.201-buster-slim: dial tcp: lookup mcr.microsoft.com on 192.168.65.5:53:
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-bust  0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.201-buster-slim:
------
ERROR: Service 'frontdesk-api' failed to build
```

Things I've tried:

- Running it again
- `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)`
- `docker login`
- Different SDK image

Here is the DOCKERFILE:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.201-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /app
# run this from repository root
COPY ./ ./ 
#RUN ls -lha .

RUN echo 'Building FrontDesk container'

WORKDIR /app/FrontDesk/src/FrontDesk.Api
#RUN ls -lha .
RUN dotnet restore

RUN dotnet build "FrontDesk.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FrontDesk.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FrontDesk.Api.dll"]
```

How can I get my build working again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mcr.microsoft.com is down at the moment

I'm receiving several different errors when pulling:

```
% docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
Error response from daemon: Get https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/: Service Unavailable

% docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
5.0: Pulling from dotnet/sdk
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: It was DNS. It’s always DNS. Sigh.

Comment: I had the same problem here

Comment: For me it was DNS as well - nslookup returned three A records for `internal.company.repository`, testing with netcat only one of the addresses actually worked... Thanks, Mordac...

Answer (score 229):

the solution that worked for me is to delete the .docker/config.json by running

```
rm  ~/.docker/config.json
```

then `docker-compose up your-services` should work

Comment: Worked for me too. But why? Would be nice to understand the underlying issue.

Comment: @egst it looks like this file gets corrupted or misconfigured, for potentially different reasons. by removing it, is created again from scratch, I have noticed this error is more likely if you are using the vs-code docker extension.

Comment: I did not even have the file :( so not worked

Comment: This worked for me; I experienced a problem shortly after moving from `docker-compose` to docker compose` (V2) so I guess there was an incompatible entry in the config

Comment: it worked for me. but days later it happened again. my `~/.docker/config.json` contained only the context I'm using. it looks clearly related with Docker Compose v2 in my case. this time I ended up removing the entire folder `~/.docker/`

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: This started happening to me after executing `docker system prune -a`

Comment: This happened to me after switching from Docker Desktop to Rancher. What helped was to run `docker logout`.

Comment: windows wsl2 worked for me

Comment: Instead of deleting the whole file, for me worked to remove only the line with `credsStore`.

Comment: windows wsl - worked for me.

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.docker/` worked in Ubuntu 22.04, thanks @logoff

Comment: Wow! That's running.

Answer (score 70):

For linux

Step 1: `sudo vi  ~/.docker/config.json`

You will see something like this:

```json
    {
      "credsStore": "desktop.exe"
    }
```

Step 2: Update `credsStore` to `credStore`

Step 3: Run your services `docker-compose up your-services`

Windows:

Step 1: Go to `C:\Users\Name\.docker`

Step 2: Open `config.json`

Step 3: Update `credsStore` to `credStore`

Step 4: Run your services `docker-compose up your-services`

Comment: This worked for me (Windows/WSL2/Ubuntu), thanks.

Comment: worked for me on m1 chip

Comment: worked on windows wsl2

Comment: it worked for me too on m1 max chip on mac

Comment: This worked for me on Mac - M2 Pro chip

Comment: this worked for me on mac with Intel

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 11/WSL2/Ubuntu. But, what's responsible for this?

Comment: This file doesn't exist in my case

Comment: Step 2 worked for me, what a weird error

Comment: It's working. May due to version update of docker desktop, it was giving issues.

Comment: This work for me on MacBook Pro - Intel

Comment: After all I just logout in docker desktop and 
and everything became fine

Answer (score 21):

In my case, it was corporate VPN that caused this issue. Once I disabled the VPN, it worked fine. Not really a solution, I admit. You could disable the VPN for the duration of this command run and enable it back.

Comment: Faced the same issue. I wish there is a better message for this.

Comment: Thank you!! I'm starting to hate Surfshark. It starts automatically and has been creating problems for me.

Comment: connecting to my personal wifi network by disconnecting from corporate Wifi/LAN helped me

Comment: same problem! thank you

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me on Mac OS X was editing the Docker Config:

```
sudo vi  ~/.docker/config.json
```

Changing

`"credsStore": "desktop"`

to

```
"credStore": "desktop"
```

And running, in my case:

```
sudo docker build -t php-demo .
```

( to build the demo/sample app )

Comment: worked for me... but why?

Comment: Because, as shown above, "credsStore" should be "credStore" - note the extra "s" in the first one.  A misspelling in the original install.

Comment: THANKS a lot, I have been struggling with this frustrating problem for few days now, all the other solutions didn't work. I even uninstalled and re-installed Docker desktop on my M1 Air, but strangely, the config file was generated by docker with "credsStore" key: with an extra "s". So frustrating problem !!! Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

Could it be that, it's getting the wrong `arch/platform` to build the image? Try specifying one in the command:

```
docker build -t auth:1.0.0 --platform=linux/arm64 .
```

getting the current arch

```bash
arch
```

Comment: Adding on to this, if you try pulling the image directly, you will get the architecture error if that is indeed the problem: `docker pull docker.io/company/image:latest` 
`no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries`

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem arose because I have Apple Silicon in my laptop, and there is no version of the image I want that is compiled for linux/arm64/v8.

To see if this is your issue, try `docker pull <image>` for more detailed error messages.

Comment: so weird, I ran the above `docker pull ...` and afterward the error then resolved itself and I could do the build like normal

Answer (score 4):

For me the problem was in the `General` settings.

uncheck `Use Docker Compose V2` and click `Apply & Restart`

Comment: I closed and opened my terminal as well.

Comment: To restart docker, find the docker icon in the 'taskbar hidden icons' right click & click the 'restart' option.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this issue while building docker container as:

**Error:**

```
 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:lts-gallium:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: ``
Applications failed at ./run:build line 18.
```

**Solution:**

I went to Docker desktop-->settings-->Docker engine-->
changed "buildkit": true to "buildkit": false

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": false
  }
}
```

Now Apply and restart docker and build the application.

Once application build successfully, revert back the changes of docker engine
"buildkit": false to "buildkit": true

```
{
  "builder": {
    "gc": {
      "defaultKeepStorage": "20GB",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  }
}
```

and rebuild application

Answer (score 1):

I think this has to do with issues trying to load the meta data of the image specified in the dockerfile from the dockerhub or the container repository of your choice.
a quick fix is to check if your internet is up or you have necessary access. this is what resolve it for me.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I use access tokens for Docker Hub and logging in again made the error go away.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was because I was using [docker-credential-helpers](https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers) in `~/.docker/config.json`.

```json
{
        "auths": {
                "ghcr.io": {},
                "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {},
                "registry-intl.eu-central-1.aliyuncs.com": {}
        },
        "credsStore": "pass"
}
```

So I needed to unlock the keystore, for example with the following command for `index.docker.io`:

```bash
pass show docker-credential-helpers/aHR0cHM6Ly9pbmRleC5kb2NrZXIuaW8vdjEv/USERNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error pop up recently and I tried changing nameservers etc. Finally restarting docker helped. `sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked is deleting the "credsStroe" from the config.json file

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using docker compose to build from a local dockerfile.
Turned out I had a `COPY` action in my dockerfile that was using a `--from=x` referencing an earlier `FROM` where I forgot to add the `AS x`.

Docker-compose didn't show any of this though. It wasnt util I ran `docker build` that it showed me the detailed info as to why it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me after adding custom nameservers.

```
   [network]
   generateResolvConf = false
```

I reverted that line on

> /etc/wsl.conf

and after doing `wsl.exe --shutdown` on the powersell and restart again docker, it worked fine again.

Answer (score 0):

It was proxy settings for me. I had proxy enabled in docker desktop. Disabling worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, faced with the same issue. As guys said - looks like it is their side issue or DNS is feeling bad. Try to pull it manually using `docker pull` few times in a row, it may help.

Also, try to switch your internet provider from cable/wireless to gsm for example if you have the ability to do it, also working solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the the token to access the registry was outdated. So make sure that `docker login your-registry`is working well.

Reference: https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/476#issuecomment-761875948

Answer (score 0):

After several weird attempts that were failing,

I just deleted the .docker folder

location: C:\Users\Name.docker

and it worked .... for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar error when building for multiple platforms

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 -t name:tag . -o type=image
```

I tried for single platform to update the base image (`linux/amd64` then `linux/arm64`)

```
docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64 -t name:tag . -o type=image
```

After done updating, I just canceled to run for both platforms and it works. In my case, there might be a bug when fetching latest base image for multiple platforms.

Comment: Yes and that bug is that it ignores proxy settings or it uses some obsolete one.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was damaged `.dockerignore` file. Just try to delete it/rename it/recreate it.

The full error I got was:

```
[+] Building 2.2s (7/16)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                               0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.31kB                                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/nginx:alpine                                                                                                                                                                    0.9s 
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16.19.1-bullseye-slim                                                                                                                                                      2.0s 
 => [angular-built 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:16.19.1-bullseye-slim@sha256:15ea844ec458ab40d10cd469352b86d82e16c3919fd1660bbfbec565fb6853a5                                                                                  0.0s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/node:16.19.1-bullseye-slim@sha256:15ea844ec458ab40d10cd469352b86d82e16c3919fd1660bbfbec565fb6853a5                                                                                                0.0s 
 => [stage-1 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:6318314189b40e73145a48060bff4783a116c34cc7241532d0d94198fb2c9629                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => resolve docker.io/library/nginx:alpine@sha256:6318314189b40e73145a48060bff4783a116c34cc7241532d0d94198fb2c9629                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => ERROR [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => transferring context:                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
------
 > [internal] load build context:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Internal desc = stream terminated by RST_STREAM with error code: PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it as below for windows machine,

1. Go to your `C://Users/YOUR_USER_FOLDER`
2. Get inside `.docker folder`
3. Remove `config.json` file
4. Using command prompt/command line/terminal, I ran `docker login` cmd, entered  username/password and login was successful.
5. Above command created `config.json` again with below contents,

   ```
   {
       "auths": {
           "https://.........
        },
       "credsStore": "wincred"
   }
   ```
6. Just changed

   ```
   "credsStore": "wincred"
   ```

   to

   ```
   "credStore": "desktop"
   ```

and started working without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things help:

```
mv ~/.docker ~/.docker_broken
```

Remove unused data to gain some space:

```
docker system prune -a
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
sudo vi  ~/.docker/config.json

sudo docker build -t myApp .
```

Answer (score -1):

[Specific solution] Only if building from a virtual environment.
Try deactivating it, event if it is the base one.
e.g. for conda:

```
conda deactivate
```

Answer (score -1):

I DELETED THE ENTIRE "C:\Users\NAME\.docker" FOLDER AND IT WORKED.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us.

Answer (score -1):

**no disk space**

I just got the exact same error and in my case the problem was that I didn't have enough disk space. I'm running docker in a VM with 32 GB virtual disk and it just ran out of all the docker images. I freed up some space and the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

Check your proxy settings. For me, this got resolved after proxy settings change

```
git config --global http.proxy proxy-eu.<name>.com:8080
```

name should be replaced

Answer (score -1):

if you write code for a node like this
FROM node: alpine
then must need to pull

docker pull node

hopefully, it was work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Structure your answer well with code parts high lighted.

Answer (score -1):

clearing disk space by deleting images & restarting docker did the trick for me.

Answer (score -1):

I restarted my PC, and it worked :D

Comment: Well, I must admit this helped in my case.

Answer (score -2):

Your session expired.

You have to log in again at https://hub.docker.com/